# python : checking if file name is a substring of another filename

Tags: python

Forgive me if this is a really simple question but I'm new to python
I have two file lists of file paths, I want to select the first file from the first list,check for the file that has a substring of the first file and run my code.

for example:

first_list:

1. first_file1 = /.../.../**testname1**.csv
2. first_file2 = /.../.../testname2.csv
3. first_file3 = /.../.../testname3.csv

second_list

1. second_file1 = /.../.../random**testname1**.csv
2. second_file2 = /.../.../randomtestname2.csv
3. second_file3 = /.../.../randomtestname3.csv
   my code should only run on first_file1 and second_file1 then move on to first_file2 and second_file2

I tried

```
if os.path.basename(first_file) in os.path.basename(second_file):
   file2 = this_file
   open(this_file,'r') as f:
     #then run my code
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, are those filenames the real names? Don't forget that `os.path.basename` includes the file extension. I'd just put this before the if statement to see if those variables are what you expect: `print(os.path.basename(first_file)`

Comment: I will check that, thanks

Comment: what if I need to look for part of the basename, instead of finding test**name1**.csv in randomtest**name1.csv**, I just want to find **name1.csv**

Comment: Posted some content as an answer, see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stripping out the file extension and see if it works, assuming those aren't the real names of the files. If the substring you're searching for isn't at the end of the file name the compare will fail because of the extension. For example:

```
"name1.csv" in "testname1.csv"  # True
"test.csv" in "testname1.csv"   # False
```

The first example works because name1.csv is in testname1.csv, but the second one fails because of the file extension.

The easiest fix is to remove the extension by just slicing off the last 4 characters, ie this:

```
my_search_string = os.path.basename(first_file)
if my_search_string[:-4] in os.path.basename(second_file):
```

`[:-4]` counts 4 characters backwards from the end of the string and returns everything else.